# Ajax data printing same data into client side over and over

Tags: php, ajax

I'm wondering whether there is a simple way to stop the same data being printed over and over.

My notification system searches from the last notification_id for a new one, if successful it puts that new data into a dic, but because the page isn't refreshed, when it then searches again it searches the same id and posts the same new id and this keeps repeating. So I thought, would it be ok to add a random number or time at the end of the url to stop this repeating so I only get new results shown in my div the once.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){


  var notification_id="<?php echo $notification_id['notification_id'] ;?>"

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(response){
if(response.num){
$("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_id).prepend('<div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'</div></nr>');

 $("#mes").html(''+ response.num + '');
}
}
});
},20000);

</script>
```

Comment: instead of prepending, why not replace?

Comment: Because I want all the other notifications to show inside the div too, the older ones. I just insert the new ones. Could you suggest anything regarding my question?

Comment: Some browsers like to mess with ajax, namely Safari. Adding this to the Ajax options helped me many times: `headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache"},`

Comment: store the already pretended id's, check if its, 'new' prepend if it is, ignore if not

Comment: In client or server side?

Comment: Save the last one's response as a client side variable... if it's the same, don't output it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this method. Could you mock an example up please?